# How do you get user OAuth for the Tumblr API in PHP?

Tags: php, api, http, oauth, tumblr

Using the default Tumblr v2 API, I'm able to connect to my application, and retrieve posts from my own account. However, I'd like users to be able to connect their *own* accounts. I've tried to figure this out but I'm not entirely sure how to use OAuth (im using [this class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html)). How is this done?

The code I'm using to retrieve dashboard posts is:

```
$consumerKey = 'xxx';
  $consumerSecret = 'xxx';
  $tumblr = new Tumblr\API\Client(
    $consumerKey,
    $consumerSecret
  );

var_dump( $tumblr->getDashboardPosts() ); // using var_dump for testing purposes only
```

This code works, but it's only returning the code for my PERSONAL account.

Comment: You should add snippets of code to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I figured it out, thanks to Github user `seejohnrun`.](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/issues/22)

```
require_once 'include/util.php';

  $consumerKey = 'XXX';
  $consumerSecret = 'XXX';
  $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
  $requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
  $requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

  // If we are visiting the first time
  if (!$_GET['oauth_verifier']) {

      // grab the oauth token
      $resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', array());
      $out = $result = $resp->body;
      $data = array();
      parse_str($out, $data);

      // tell the user where to go
      echo '<a href="https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $data['oauth_token'].'"> GO </a>';
      $_SESSION['t']=$data['oauth_token'];
      $_SESSION['s']=$data['oauth_token_secret'];

  } else {

      $verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];

      // use the stored tokens
      $client->setToken($_SESSION['t'], $_SESSION['s']);

      // to grab the access tokens
      $resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $verifier));
      $out = $result = $resp->body;
      $data = array();
      parse_str($out, $data);

      // and print out our new keys we got back
      $token = $data['oauth_token'];
      $secret = $data['oauth_token_secret'];
      echo "token: " . $token . "<br/>secret: " . $secret;

      // and prove we're in the money
      $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);
      $info = $client->getUserInfo();
      echo "<br/><br/>congrats " . $info->user->name . "!";

  }
```